# Are the final events of DBZ considered canon?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-z

In *Dragon Ball Z*, the series flashes forward 10 years after the defeat of Buu and we're introduced to things like Gohan and Videl's daughter Pan, lazy teenage versions of Trunks and Goten, and a reincarnated Buu (Uub).

Since *Dragon Ball Super* begins sometime shortly after the defeat of Buu, are the flash-forward events of *DBZ* wiped from canon, similar to the *GT* history?

My biggest point of confusion is the fact that Pan is 4 in the final events of *DBZ*, which means she was born 6 years after Goku kills Buu. But at the beginning of *Dragon Ball Super*, Gohan and Videl announce they're pregnant with Pan. This could be explained easily if *Super* picked up some 5 years after Buu's defeat, but Goten and Trunks appear to be the same age as they were in *Z*. So it seems likely that Pan was born way earlier than 6 years after Buu's defeat.

Do these events reconcile or was the end of *Z* undone to make room for *Super* to tell new stories?

Comment: This question looked familiar, and then I remembered seeing it on Scifi-Fantasy. So welcome to Anime and Manga!

Comment: @Wondercricket - Haha, yeah, I didn't realize there was an Anime & Manga SE otherwise I would've just posted here. It's a much better fit here.

Answer (score 2):

In *Dragon Ball Super*, Dende makes a mention to Uub and he tells Goku it would be good if he trains him. That's meant to connect *Dragon Ball Super* with the end of *Dragon Ball Z*.

As for Trunks and Goten appearance, in *Dragon Ball*, 4 years have passed between Goku meeting Bulma and killing King Piccolo, and his appearance (which is almost identical to Goten by the way) doesn't change. So yes, the final events of *Dragon Ball Z* are canon.

Comment: So you're saying that 5 years or so HAS in fact passed between Goku killing Buu and the start of Dragon Ball Super? Do you have anything authoritative that suggests that?

Comment: I'm not making any conclusions of possible or not continuity mistakes. You asked if the end of Dragon Ball Z was canon, and I told you the writers wrote a piece of episode in Dragon Ball Super meant to connect that with the end of Dragon Ball Z, because it's canon. How you make everything fits after that - if there is an actual problem, or if they actually care to make it fit at all - it's another issue. BTW, you have now parts of Dragon Ball Super which has 3 versions of the same story, movie, series and manga. So it's not like they are going to even try to make everything fits together.

Comment: Also remember that Akira Toriyama is notorious for writing by the seat of his pants.  There have been incidents where he has done things that don't jive with previous cannon.  It's just part of the DB universe that there are some plot holes.

Comment: @ThelronCheek  Actually, 4 years have passed since Goku and co defeat Majin Buu(Age 774) and skipping to the Battle of Gods arc which happens in Age 778.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, with regard to your confusion about Pan, she was born in the *Age 779*.  This is after the *Age 778* when the Battle of Gods arc first takes place and Videl is pregnant. Goku leaves to train with Uub in the *Age 784*. So yes! **It is possible for Pan to be four** during the final events of *DBZ*.

With regard to your main question, the answer would be **yes and no**. The reason I say that is because if you were to take ***DBZ* and *DBS*** as a whole and look at the events, it does make sense in a way and seems canon so you could consider it to be canon. As the same ending of Goku going to train with Uub can be found in both the manga and the anime, you can't necessarily consider it to be filler.

However, the reason I said the answer could be **yes and no**, is because the *DBS* series was thought off after a significant amount of time. Over the years, for the purpose of extending the series, a lot of prior information has been retconned simply for the purpose of convenience. For instance, *DBS* Broly retcons the original series of *Dragon Ball* with regard to Goku's age. The character of Broly was re-introduced and dramatically changed. The power scaling of characters increased dramatically. Currently, the manga is working on a *chapter after the events of DBS Broly and the T.O.P*, and we don't know whether the series is going to resume or whether we are going to see several more arcs after which replace the Martial Arts Tournament that takes place

The reason I say this is because the only reason Goku entered the tournament was because he was very excited to fight Uub (Kid Buu). Kid Buu was basically one of the strongest antagonists in *DBZ* whom Goku lost against, so it would make sense for him to be excited to fight him. Goku has clearly fought several antagonists much superior to Kid Buu over the years in *DBS* and it wouldn't make sense why he'd be as excited to fight someone several times weaker. That said, Goku is excited to fight anyone most of the time so the ending could still exist.

In conclusion, if you take the series as a whole now, yes! The ending can be fit in. However, it could very easily be retconned if the series were to resume.

[image: DBZ Manga ending]

Comment: IIRC, Broly was OAV-only material, hence was not canon in DBZ

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes, it is canon.

The boys look the same age, but they are in fact older. They have referred several times throughout the series that Saiyans age slower so they can fight longer. So they keep looking young for about 5-10 years, then have a dramatic change. Like teen Gohan to adult Goten and Trunks are 14-15 respectfully, being 1 year age gap between them in *Super*, which would age up to about 19-20 in the final events of *Z*, which would add up to the grow up making them look teen.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's non-canon.

*Dragon Ball Super* is based after the Buu saga. When Goku first goes Super Saiyan God, Goten and Trunks are still young kids. At the end of *Z* time skip, Goten and Trunks are teenagers. Toriyama has stated that *DBS* is canon but *GT* is not, and the end of *Z* is basically a pathway to *GT*. Therefore, the end of *Z* cannot be canon. Toriyama stated that the end of *Z* was a side story, anyway.